Unauthorized Error Using YouTube Data API with Service Account in Node.js
I am attempting to upload videos to YouTube using the YouTube Data API and a service account in my Node.js backend. However, I keep encountering an "Unauthorized" error. Here is a summary of what I have done so far:
Set Up Service Account:
Created a service account in the Google Cloud Console and downloaded the JSON key file.
Enabled domain-wide delegation and provided the necessary permissions in the G Suite Admin console.
Granted the following scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload.
Backend Code:
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const credentials = require('./path/to/your/service-account-file.json');

const router = express.Router();

const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'];

// Initialize the JWT client
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  credentials.client_email,
  null,
  credentials.private_key,
  scopes,
  'user@example.com' // G Suite user email
);

// Function to upload a video
async function uploadVideo(req, res) {
  const filePath = req.file.path;
  const { fileName } = req.body;
  try {
    const youtube = google.youtube({
      version: 'v3',
      auth,
    });

    if (!filePath) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'File data not provided' });
    }

    // Video resource
    const videoParams = {
      part: 'snippet,status',
      requestBody: {
        snippet: {
          title: req.body.title || 'Test',
          description: '',
          tags: [],
        },
        status: {
          privacyStatus: 'public',
        },
      },
      media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
      },
    };

    // Execute the request to upload the video
    const response = await youtube.videos.insert(videoParams, {
      onUploadProgress: (evt) => {
        const progress = (evt.bytesRead / videoParams.media.body._readableState.length) * 100;
        console.log(`${Math.round(progress)}% uploaded`);
      },
    });

    console.log('Video uploaded:', response.data);
    const videoUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${response.data.id}`;

    // Send response with video URL
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Video uploaded successfully', videoUrl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading video:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload video', message: error.message });
  }
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'uploads',
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, `${Date.now()}.mp4`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024 },
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    const { mimetype } = file;
    if (mimetype.startsWith('video/')) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(new Error('Invalid file type'));
    }
  },
});

router.post('/youtube-upload', upload.single('file'), uploadVideo);

module.exports = router;
Frontend Code:

javascript
Copy code
const handleClick = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  formData.append('fileName', file.name);

  if (file.type.startsWith('video/')) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/youtube-upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to upload video to YouTube');
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('YouTube upload successful', data);

      // Update state with the video URL or handle success
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading video to YouTube:', error.message);
      // Handle error (e.g., show error message to user)
    }
  } else {
    // Handle non-video uploads
  }
}; ```
Despite these steps, I am getting the following error message:


GaxiosError: Unauthorized
I have ensured that:

The service account has the appropriate permissions.
The JWT token is correctly generated and used.
What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.


Check this answer and related answers. Also, would be good to get the full error detail.
